# Building a query URL in Scala

Tags: strings, scala

I'm working on a webapp in ScalaJS and want to create a query url for requesting some JSON.

Right now I'm using a method called urlBuilder to take the query options from an Options case class and return a String that represents a usable query URL. The urlBuilder method, despite my best efforts, has become somewhat ugly.

Am I missing out on any syntactic sugar or language features that could make this a little easier to understand/cleaner looking? Is pattern matching + string interpolation the best strategy here?

```
case class GameRegions(americas: Boolean, europe: Boolean, asia: Boolean)

case class Options(startRank: Option[Int], endRank: Option[Int], startDate: Option[Date], endDate: Option[Date], startTime: Option[Date], endTime: Option[Date], regions: GameRegions, gameMode: Boolean)

//Builds the URL based on the provided options object
def urlBuilder(baseUrl: String, o: Options): String = {
  baseUrl + "?" + (o.startRank match {
    case Some(x) => s"rank[0]=$x&"
    case None => ""
  }) + (o.endRank match {
    case Some(x) => s"rank[1]=$x&"
    case None => ""
  }) + (o.startDate match {
    case Some(x) => s"added[0]=@${x.getTime / 1000}&"
    case None => ""
  }) + (o.endDate match {
    case Some(x) => s"added[1]=@${x.getTime / 1000}&"
    case None => ""
  }) + (o.startTime match {
    case Some(x) => s"time[0]=@${x.getTime / 1000}&"
    case None => ""
  }) + (o.endTime match {
    case Some(x) => s"time[1]=@${x.getTime / 1000}&"
    case None => ""
  }) + (o.regions match {
    case GameRegions(false, false, false) => ""
    case GameRegions(x, y, z) => {
      var i: Int = -1
      if (x) {
        i = i + 1
        s"region[$i]=Americas&"
      } else {
        ""
      } + (if (y) {
        i = i + 1
        s"region[$i]=Europe&"
      } else {
        ""
      }) + (if (z) {
        i = i + 1
        s"region[$i]=Asia&"
      } else {
        ""
      }) + "&"
    }
  }) + s"format[0]=${if (o.gameMode) "Standard" else "Wild"}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes pattern matching over Option could be replaced with fold or map/getOrElse

```
o.startRank.fold("")(x => s"rank[0]=$x&")

o.startRank.map(x => s"rank[0]=$x&").getOrElse("")
```

---

You could notice that url parameters have a pattern `key=value` joined with `&`. To leverage this pattern url builder could be split into separate steps:

- create a map `Map[String,String]` of parameters i.e.

  ```
  Map(
    "rank[0]" -> o.startRank.fold("")(_.toString),      
    ...
    "time[0]" -> o.startTime.map(time => time.getTime/1000).map(_.toString).getOrElse("")
  ```
- join parameters into string

  ```
  map.filter(_._2.nonEmpty).map { 
    case (key, value) => s"$key=$value" 
  }.mkString("&")
  ```